# Обернуть запрос

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
SELECT * 
    FROM  ( 
    SELECT `user_id` as ids,`created`,`order_id`
    FROM `order`
    WHERE 
    `created` < ( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) 
    ORDER BY `created` DESC
    ) AS orders 
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON `orders`.`ids` =  `users`.`user_id`
    GROUP BY `user_id` 
    HAVING count( `user_id` ) >=1

как правильно написать данный запрос  в zend framework?( Zend ORM/Query_Builder)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$asd =  Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getInstance();
$time = Zend_DATA::now();
$tmpdata['day'] = 30;
$select1 = $asd
    ->select()
    ->from('order',array('user_id as ids', 'created','order_id'))
    ->where('created<?',$time - $tmpdata['day'])->order('created DESC');

$select2 = $asd ->select
            ->from($select1.'as orders')
            ->joinLeft('users','orders.ids= users.user_id')
            ->group('user_id')
            ->HAVING('count(users.user_id)>=1');
```

ну оно 100% с первого раза не будет пахать ибо у меня базы нету. но править не много будет.